# Possible to get color with string?

Tags: android, string, colors, android-resources

In my `values` folder I have `my_colors.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Orange -->
    <color name="orangePrimary">#f6a02d</color>
    <color name="orange1">#e3952a</color>
    <color name="orange2">#da8f28</color>
    <color name="orange3">#d08926</color>
</resources>
```

Is there a way to get these colors just with the string of its name?
Something like `view.setBackgroundColor.getColor("orange1");`

For images you have this `getResources().getIdentifier("my_image", "drawable", getPackageName());`

Hope you guys know what I mean.
Greetings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried the following:

```java
// java
Resources res = context.getResources();
String packageName = context.getPackageName();

int colorId = res.getIdentifier("my_color", "color", packageName);
int desiredColor = res.getColor(colorId);
```

```kotlin
// kotlin
val res: Resources = context.getResources()
val packageName: String = context.getPackageName()

val colorId: Int = res.getIdentifier("my_color", "color", packageName)
val desiredColor: Int = res.getColor(colorId)
```

Hope it helps!

---

**Note:** This is deprecated, instead you could do the following, which handles both pre and post Marshmallow (API 23):

```java
// java
Resources res = context.getResources();
String packageName = context.getPackageName();

int colorId = res.getIdentifier("my_color", "color", packageName);
int desiredColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorId);
```

```kotlin
// kotlin
val res: Resources = context.getResources()
val packageName: String = context.getPackageName()

val colorId: Int = res.getIdentifier("my_color", "color", packageName)
val desiredColor: Int = ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorId)
```

Comment: Yes, Reaz Murshed suggested that before he changed his answer. Your "desiredColour" is always wrong. I don't know why, but in my case its always that dark transparent purple.

Comment: Of course, I have updated my answer.
You firstly get the resource id, then you must get the color from the resource id.

Comment: UUhhhh, thats working! But didn't I get problems in the future with that deprecated method getColor() ?

Comment: You should be fine for now, if it causes any problems in the future, you can still fix the problem.

Comment: Could you give me the Kotlin version of that please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65445066/possible-to-get-color-with-string-in-kotlin

Comment: @Jevon the upper post has been edited, thanks for the notice. I've also added the correct implementation since it handles both pre and post Marshmallow (v23) versions.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got the color by name using reflection now and got this working in my side.

You need to write a function like this.

```
public int getColorByName(String name) {
    int colorId = 0;

    try {
        Class res = R.color.class;
        Field field = res.getField(name);
        colorId = field.getInt(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return colorId;
}
```

Now get the resource id using

```
int resourceId = getColorByName("orange1");
```

And **set the drawable as a resource** in your `ImageView` like this.

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(resourceId);
```

**I tried setting `img.setBackgroundColor(resourceId)` which was setting the wrong color.**

In your case I would like to suggest to keep the colors in a typed array in your `res/values/arrays.xml` like this

```
<array name="colors">
    <item>#FFFF0000</item>
    <item>#FF00FF00</item>
    <item>#FF0000FF</item>
</array>
```

See the developers doc for [Typed Array](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray) about how to use it.

Comment: Yeah, tried that, put returned the wrong color. A color I'm not created, some kind of dark transparent purple.

Comment: See the updated answer please. Got it working in my side.

Comment: Thank you, looks nice and clean. Unfortunately its not working for me. I need to change the color of my statusbar, some views and some imageviews. So maybe .setBackgroundResource working but setStatusBarColor didn't. I think I have to make some kind of HashMap<String, Integer> that store my colors I think =(

Comment: Okay, I tried that, but I get the same problem. To choose the right array I need to type R.array.orange for example so its the same as in the beginning. But I vote that up. Maybe someone elses problem solved with your solution. I make a HashMap with my colors now.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you are using only R it might take material base Resource( com.google.android.material.R.color). so, you need to use below the code with your package name Resource(com.example.app.R.color)

button.setBackgroundColor(context.resources.getColor(com.example.app.R.color.colorPrimary))
```

Answer (score -1):

Starting from Android Support Library 23, a new **getColor()** method has been added to **ContextCompat**.

So, just call:

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);
```

The other one is depracated **getResources.getColor()** So you need to implement the above. No any way for just passing the name of color to access it. you have to give color id from your color file.

Comment: thats so uncool! I have 8 different colors each with 4 different color temperatures. For knowing which one is needed I get a string like "orange".