# How to write binding adapter to set background colour when the colour is coming from api as hex code?

Tags: android, kotlin

Background colour is coming from API in this form FFF9E6.I am using data binding.I am not able to understand how I can set it as background colour. I believe binding adapter would work but not sure how to write it. How can I write binding adapter for the same?

Answer (score 2):

This code worked in my case.

```
@BindingAdapter("android:backgroundColor")
fun ViewGroup.setBackground(backgroundColor: String) {

val color: Int = try {
    Color.parseColor(background)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Color.parseColor("#$background")
}
setBackgroundColor(color)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem a few months back. what I did was stored the data coming from API to one POJO class. Then in an XML file using that POJO class member as data binding variable. 
i.e.

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/_8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/_8dp"
            app:color="@{item.color}" />
```

and it's binding adapter

```
@BindingAdapter("bind:color")
public static void setStatus(TextView textView, String color) {

}
```

Comment: I am storing the data in POJO class. The background colour is coming in hex code without the "#". I tried the following:

Comment: app:background = "@{'#'+var.color}" . This didn't work

Comment: Does it work with a custom getter, e.g: getFullColor() which returns the color code including the hashtag ? Sorry, I'm not yet familiar with databinding.

Comment: @humbleDev read the last line of XML file its custom binding. Use custom binding it'll work and you got color in a simple string from right?.there is no direct API for setting background color dynamically passing the hex code. you need to use setBackgroungResource() for that

Comment: follow this quetion for that https://stackoverflow.com/q/1466788/7271231

Comment: Color is coming in this form FFF9E6. I am not sure what you meant by status of type boolean. Could you help me by providing me solution in my case?

Comment: hi, I've updated the answer. in the function body, you need to put the following logic which is given in the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39817392/7271231