# Possible to get color with string in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Ive had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817299/possible-to-get-color-with-string) question but as of the time i typed this question, there aren't any answers with Kotlin code.

in my `colours.xml` file how would i access colours like these for example using a string?

```
<resources>
    <!-- Orange -->
    <color name="orangePrimary">#f6a02d</color>
    <color name="orange1">#e3952a</color>
    <color name="orange2">#da8f28</color>
    <color name="orange3">#d08926</color>
</resources>
```

The Java version is apparently this

```
int desiredColour = getResources().getColor(getResources().getIdentifier("my_color", "color", getPackageName()));
```

when android studio translates the code i get this

```
val desiredColour: Int = getResources().getColor(
                                    getResources().getIdentifier(
                                        "my_color",
                                        "color",
                                        getPackageName()
                                    )
```

However `packageName()` and `getResources()` turn out red for some reason which means there is an error

So what would the Kotlin version be?

Comment: You can copy-paste Java code into a Kotlin file, and the IDE will automatically convert it to Kotlin for you.

Comment: When i use the code above i get the following translation which has red coloured code, meaning errors or code with a lot of different libraries to choose from, i dot know whats the right one.. val desiredColour: Int = getResources().getColor(
                                    getResources().getIdentifier(
                                        "my_color",
                                        "color",
                                        getPackageName()
                                    )
                                )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one possible explanation for this. getPackageName() and getResources() are not present where you are pasting the code.

For example if I paste your code in an activity, everything seems good.

```
val desiredColour = resources.getColor(resources.getIdentifier("my_color", "color", packageName))
```

with theme:

```
val desiredColour = resources.getColor(resources.getIdentifier("my_color", "color", packageName),theme)
```

But if I paste it inside fragment, I need to reference the activity of that fragment to get the package name.

```
val desiredColour = resources.getColor(resources.getIdentifier("my_color", "color", activity?.packageName))
```

with theme:

```
val desiredColour = resources.getColor(resources.getIdentifier("my_color", "color", activity?.packageName),activity?.theme)
```

And if for some reason you are pasting it elsewhere besides activity or fragment, you need to pass context or activity to call those method.

```
object TestSingleObject {
    fun getDesiredColour(context: Context) =
        context.resources.getColor(context.resources.getIdentifier("my_color", "color", context.packageName))
}
```

with theme:

```
object TestSingleObject {
    fun getDesiredColour(context: Context) =
        context.resources.getColor(context.resources.getIdentifier("my_color", "color", context.packageName), context.theme)
}
```

Comment: My other problem now is that getColor() is deprecated.

Comment: @Jevon That is not a problem. Don't use the deprecated method. Instead, use the updated getColor method by providing the theme. Providing a theme shouldn't be difficult. Check my updated answer.

Comment: When i do the updated version i then get this error `Call requires API level 23 (current min is 14): android.content.res.Resources#getColor` by the way, i need a min 14.

Comment: @Jevon Yes, the overloaded getColor method with the theme was introduced much later. To use the updated method you need to update your min sdk version or make a backward compatible method to get color based on the running sdk version of the user.

Comment: Use ``ResourcesCompat.getColor`` instead (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/res/ResourcesCompat) - there's a bunch of ``ThingCompat`` libraries to help your code run on a range of API levels

Comment: @Jevon If my answer helped you find a solution, please accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set:

```
snackBar_View.setBackgroundColor(context.resources.getColor(com.example.app.R.color.colorPrimary))
```

Instead of:

```
snackBar_View.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.redish))
```